# timeouts (ERR_CONNECTION_RESET) on seemingly random files after upgrading to HTTPS

Tags: jquery, login

I have a WordPress site on a managed host (discountasp.net) that has run for several years. A few days ago I upgraded the managed site to use https by installing an SSL certificate (the actual installation was done by discountasp.net). As part of the troubleshooting so far I have upgraded to PHP 7.0 and WordPress 5.6.

Now, when loading any WordPress page, including the admin login page, I get random timeouts on various files. If I look in Chrome dev tools, I see that many files load immediately, but one or more time out.

[image: a file failing to load in two minutes]

In the example above, the file is jquery.js, but other files often fail to load also, especially .css files. Note that in the example above, it is the wp-admin page that is failing to load. I have also renamed the `wp-content/plugins` and `wp-content/themes` directories, so I don't believe any plugins or themes are involved here. So I believe all I'm trying to do here is visit the login page for a newly installed WordPress 5.6.

I can't tell if this is a problem in WordPress or a problem with discountasp.net. So far discountasp.net tech support has not been able to say anything useful. As I say, this site ran for years without trouble until I installed the SSL certificate. And that's the only change I made, so presumably that's what's making these files fail to load, but I don't understand why.

Also, I did trying adding these lines to wp-config.php.

```
define('FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', false);
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', false);
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://www.integratedinsightsconsulting.com/' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://www.integratedinsightsconsulting.com/' );
```

That produced different behavior, but still broken. I was able to use the login screen to log in, but when the dashboard loads it times out loading some styles:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This was resolved by discountasp.net. Their note: The other issue is because the older IIS 7 server did not support TLS 1.2 protocol which your application required for SSL to work. I resolved it by migrating your site to our newer IIS 10 web server where TLS 1.2 is supported.